# how can i calculate big O for this loop?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, big-o

I want to ask you how can I calculate big o for this loop?'
the x++ is clearly O(1) right? I don't understand the i*2 part...
I watched videos on YouTube but i can't solve this.
I will be thankful if you guys can help me understand this.

```
for(int i{3} ; i<=n ; i*=2){
      x++;
   }
```

Comment: `i = 3, 6, 12, 24, 48, ...`

Comment: Since `i` grows exponentially, the computational complexity of the loop is `O(log n)`.

Comment: let's say, you need x steps to reach n. So, the eq. becomes 3*2^x = n; 2^x = (n/3);
so log_2(n/3) =x;

for n=99, we can calculate, log_2(99/3) = log_2(33), which is >5 and <7, so we can say 6.
we can also see the progression as 3,6,12,24,48,96. So big O is logarithmic and which it should never exceed and clearly it depends on the starting value of i.